# Задание Кто хочет стать миллионером

Tags: c++, switch, case, if

Задали сделать игру Кто хочет стать миллионером.Весь код прописал , сделал вопросы , подсказки. Но проблема не получается сделать так чтобы они если использовались больше нельзя было использовать. Пытался через if но не получилось
Помогите пожалуйста ну или объясните

```
switch (hint)
            {
            case (1):
            {
                cout << "Вы использовали подсказку '50 на 50' " << endl << endl;
                cout << "Как называется оптическое устройство, необходимое фотокамере ?" << endl;
                cout << "a)негатив" << endl;
                cout << "b)объектив*" << endl;

                cin >> answer;

                switch (answer)
                {

                case 'a':

                    cout << "Ваш ответ неверный. Вы проиграли " << endl;

                    isGame = false;

                    continue;

                case 'b':
                    cout << "Ваш ответ верный. Вы выйграли 100 $" << endl << endl;
                    break;

                default:

                    cout << "НЕВЕРНОЕ ДЕЙСТВИЕ !!!" << endl;

                    isGame = false;

                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: В чем проблема поясните понятней.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно просто поставить какой-нибудь флаг с количеством доступных подсказок и разрешать вызывать подсказки пока флаг не ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Если не учитывать ваши ошибки и отвечать только  на ваш вопрос :  "чтобы они если использовались больше нельзя было использовать ", то например так:

```
bool m[3] = {0}; //насколько я помню, подсказок там всего 3 
int hint_counter = 0; //счетчик  использованных подсказок
//Если для ответа нужна подсказка, то вводим номер подсказки   
cin >> hint;
// поменяйте значение соответствующего элемента массива
m[hint - 1] = 1; 
//и увеличиваем счетчик с каждой использованной подсказкой
++ hint_counter;
// Если для ответа нужна еще подсказка, то вводим еще раз ее номер
// и проверяем, была ли уже такая подсказка? 
if (hint_counter <= 3) {
    while (m[hint - 1]) {
        // подсказка использована, выбираем другую подсказку
        cin >> hint;
     }
}
else
    //все подсказки использованы
```

Другие способы: это использование структур пар, стандартных контейнеров, но судя по вашему коду, вы их еще не изучали...